# Reconfigure windows after installation

Tags: powershell, windows-8, batch-file, scripting, registry

I am looking to reconfigure Windows 8 after it has already been installed. Basically I have a base image that I will apply. After that is complete, I want to be able to run either a script of an exe of some sort that will setup the user accounts with passwords, add any applications that were not on the base image, change permissions and registry entries, and copy certain files to overwrite the original ones. My goal is to be able to do this on any machine that is running Windows 8 as long as I have administrative access as I will be using this on several remote locations. None of the files that I will be copying over are too big, so this is something that I want to be able to use over a network, and quickly if possible.

I know all of the settings that I want to change, but I am unsure how to go about creating the accounts with passwords, and setting them up automatically. I don't want to have to rely on someone onsite to configure these PCs, so automatic is the key. Any insight on doing this with a single click would be great.

Comment: Are you open to purchasing a solution, or are you limited to whatever comes with Windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you will be able to accomplish all of this using a script.  All of this can be accomplished by deploying a custom image to a computer.  We use SCCM for this kind of task, but there are many other alternatives.  If I were you I would look in to something like SCCM or WDS.

You can find more info here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd379586(v=vs.85).aspx

SCCM:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/system-center/configuration-manager-2012-overview.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Powershell should let you achieve most of the things you require. The following list isn't definitive guide, but it should get you going.

- To execute your script on a remote machine use **Invoke-Command**:

  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx
- Active Directory administration

  http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh852274%28v=wps.630%29.aspx
- How to modify the registry:

  http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/05/12/weekend-scripter-use-powershell-to-easily-modify-registry-property-values.aspx
- Copying files:

  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156818.aspx

  You can also call robocopy from with your script if that better meets your file copying needs better.
- App installation:

  Take a look at http://chocolatey.org/. Alternatively you can download the app install files and run them from within your script. I scripted the install of ruby and it's associated devkit using this method; however I can now achieve this using chocolatey.